# Odd behaviour of "out" argument in torch.empty()

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, overwrite, tensor

I have a sample tensor like this:

```
In [137]: x = x.new_ones((5, 3), dtype=torch.double)    
In [138]: x
Out[138]: 
tensor([[1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1.]], dtype=torch.float64)
```

Now, I want to free the memory of this tensor by overwriting the contents using `torch.empty()` which takes an `out` argument.

```
In [139]: torch.empty((5, 3), out=x)
Out[139]: 
tensor([[1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1.]], dtype=torch.float64)
```

However, the values in the original tensor `x` still remains the same. If this is the case, then what is the purpose of this keyword argument `out` in `torch.empty`? What am I missing here?

Comment: Why did you think this would free any memory?  The whole point of `.empty()` is to produce a tensor of a specific shape, with no specific contents - you will presumably be using it in some operation that overwrites everything, so clearing the initial contents would be wasted effort.  The `out` parameter seems like it would only be useful in cases where you're changing some detail of an existing (but no longer needed) tensor - changing the shape from (5,3) to (3,5) perhaps; it would be faster to reconfigure the existing object than to allocate a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/aten/src/ATen/native/TensorFactories.cpp#L112) the C++ implementation of `empty` with an out param from the source code.

```
Tensor& empty_out(Tensor& result, IntList size) {
  if (result.is_sparse()) {
    result.sparse_resize_and_clear_(size, size.size(), 0);
  } else {
    result.resize_(size);
  }
  return result;
}
```

So for dense tensors all it does is resize the tensor appropriately - in your case the size is the same.

```
In [21]: x = torch.ones((5, 3), dtype=torch.double)                                                                                                                                        

In [22]: torch.empty((2, 3), out=x)                                                                                                                                                        
Out[22]: 
tensor([[1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1.]], dtype=torch.float64)

In [23]: torch.empty((2, 8), out=x)                                                                                                                                                        
Out[23]: 
tensor([[ 1.0000e+00,  1.0000e+00,  1.0000e+00,  1.0000e+00,  1.0000e+00,
          1.0000e+00,  1.0000e+00,  1.0000e+00],
        [ 1.0000e+00,  1.0000e+00,  1.0000e+00,  1.0000e+00,  1.0000e+00,
          1.0000e+00,  1.0000e+00, 4.6631e-310]], dtype=torch.float64)
```

First of all, `empty` doesn't free memory - it only cares about allocation of a tensor of an appropriate size. In your case such a tensor has already been allocated, so `empty` has nothing to do.. it is not going to go allocate a new empty tensor somewhere else in memory. In the second `empty` example above we are forced to allocate for a tensor with a larger size (2 * 8 = 16 compared to 5 * 3 = 15), and we can see the last element in this empty array is garbage, since it is beyond the contiguous memory block that had previously been initialized. `empty` won't force-clear your whole tensor to 0 or something like that because again, it is uninitialized data.